# PHPMailer When Displayed Received/Sent Emails On Native Mobile Client Reader The Email Doesn't Display Correctly?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm working with the PHPMailer and I'm having a small issue with the output of the email when read on a native mobile email. When displayed on a desktop the email displays perfectly as expected. However, when I try reading them via a native email reader such as the pre-installed "Mail" apps on iPhone or Android the emails display letter by letter going vertically, example below:

**Display on Native Mobile Apps**

> 2
>
> 0
>
> /
>
> 0
>
> 8
>
> /
>
> 2
>
> 0
>
> 1
>
> 8

**Display on Desktop or Gmail Mobile App:**

> 20/08/2018

Has anyone experienced this issue, as I have no idea why this would happen, it does this with the entire email? But strangely only with the native email apps, as when read through Gmail it displays fine.

Thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
<?php
    //Get Date
    $_todaysDate = new DateTime();
    $todaysDate = $_todaysDate->format('d/m/Y');

    //Set Email Main Body
    $body1 = '<img style="margin-left:25%" src="images/DocHeader.png" width="50%">';
    $body2 = '<br>'.$todaysDate;
    $body3 = '<br><br>Dear Full Name,<br>';
    $body4 = '<br>Email Full Body:';
    $body5 = '<br><img style="margin-left:25%" src="images/DocFooter.png" width="50%">';

    //Set Email Main Body (Footer)
    $footer1 = '<strong>Email From</strong>';
    $footer2 = '<strong>My Footer</strong>';

    //String Together Body & Footer
    $body = $body1.'<p style="margin-left:30%;margin-right:25%;">'.$body2.$body3.$body4.$body5.'</p>'.$body19.'<h4>'.$footer1.'</h4><p>'.$footer2.'</p>';

    //Start Email
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); 

    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                               // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'mail.example.com;';                    // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'username@example.com';             // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'password';                         // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Set Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('info@example.com', 'Info');
    $mail->addAddress('toEmail@example.com', 'To Name');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Info');
    $mail->AddBCC("log@example.com", "Email Logs");

    //Set Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Email Subject';
    $mail->Body    = ($body);
    $mail->AltBody = '';

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $locationLogin = 'Location: FailedLocation.php';
        header($locationLogin);
    } 
    else {
        $locationLogin = 'Location: SuccessLocation.php';
        header($locationLogin);
    }
```

?>

Comment: I would say that all those `margin-left` and `margin-right` instructions nested as you have has basically used all the small device real estate up as margins

Comment: You're correct, I've removed the margins and images and this has resolved the issue